# Openlayers-3: How do I bind zoom-events to Controls or document

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3, pinchzoom

How do I bind zoom-events to an ol.Control or on `document`?

Openlayers (3.7.0) binds serveral zoom-events (interactions, pinchzoom) on `.ol-viewport`, but they are only triggered on the `<canvas>`-Element.

In my case I do a pinchzoom on a custom control (a `div` with some text) and the browser is zooming instead of the map/view.

How I'm able to change that behaviour?

A solution on `document` would be great, because if a layer is still loading and I do a `pinchzoom` it is also triggered to the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controls are added inside the `ol-overlaycontainer-stopevent` div by default, which prevent events to propagate to the map. See in: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.7.0/apidoc/ol.control.Control.html, more specifically:

> A control is a visible widget with a DOM element in a fixed position
>   on the screen. They can involve user input (buttons), or be
>   informational only; the position is determined using CSS. By default
>   these are placed in the container with CSS class name
>   ol-overlaycontainer-stopevent, but can use any outside DOM element.

There's an other div that doesn't: `ol-overlaycontainer`, which can be obtained using `map.getOverlayContainer()`.  Unfortunately, this method doesn't have the `@api` flag, i.e. it is not exported.  You can still obtain it using `map.getViewport()` and use (let's say) jQuery to find it inside the map viewport.

Give that div as target of your control and events should be propagated down to the map.  From `map.js, getOverlayContainer`:

```
/**
 * Get the element that serves as the container for overlays.  Elements added to
 * this container will let mousedown and touchstart events through to the map,
 * so clicks and gestures on an overlay will trigger {@link ol.MapBrowserEvent}
 * events.
 * @return {Element} The map's overlay container.
 */
```

Comment: thank you very much! I was able to set the target to `map.getOverlayContainer()` on the control and the events were propagated down to the map.